# Pass <p:selectOneListbox var="ch"> as argument of <h:commandLink action>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandlink, selectonelistbox

I'm facing problem with passing object to backing bean from `actionListener` in commandLink. What I have, is a bean `MeasureBean` and a `xhtml` file, that uses the bean.

In the xhtml I have:

```
<p:selectOneListbox var="ch">
    <f:selectItems value="#{MeasureBean.checkpoints}" var="cp" itemValue="#{cp}" />
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{ch.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:commandLink actionListener="#{MeasureBean.onCheckpointRemoved(ch)}">
            <h:graphicImage library="#{ctx.theme}" name="images/delete.gif" />
            <f:ajax event="click" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </p:column>
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

In the bean I have method:

```
public void onCheckpointRemoved(Checkpoint viewCheckpoint) {
    System.out.println(viewCheckpoint);
    // TODO
}
```

The problem is, that regardless of whethert I use the tag `<f:ajax>` or not, the parameter viewCheckpoint of the method in bean is always null. I need to pass that parameter to the bean. It doesn't have to be the whole object, it is allowed to pass just the id of the checkpoint. What I also tried, was:

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{MeasureBean.onCheckpointRemoved(cp)}">
```

(`cp` instead of `ch`). But no difference.

Please help,

Mateusz

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the value of `<p:selectOneListBox>`. Also, you'll have to create a converter.

You can check an example of converter in [PrimeFaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/listbox.xhtml)

```
<p:selectOneListbox var="ch" value="#{MeasureBean.checkPointTest}" converter="checkPointConverter">
<f:selectItems value="#{MeasureBean.checkpoints}" var="cp" itemValue="#{cp}" />
<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{ch.name}" />
</p:column>
<p:column>
    <h:commandLink actionListener="#{MeasureBean.onCheckpointRemoved(ch)}">
        <h:graphicImage library="#{ctx.theme}" name="images/delete.gif" />
        <f:ajax event="click" />
    </h:commandLink>
</p:column>
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

---

```
Checkpoint checkPointTest;
// getter/setter....
public void onCheckpointRemoved(Checkpoint viewCheckpoint) {
System.out.println(viewCheckpoint);
// TODO
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pellizon. I tried your proposal, but now the listbox it doesn't render its content at all. No items in the box. I think, that the `<f:selectItems>` tag is needed in the definition of listbox.

Comment: Check the answer again! Now it's a little more accurate shot :)

Comment: Thanks! That's the same way, that I did it, isn't it? The only difference is value and the presence of converter...   

Edit: I managed to solve the problem with a JS "hack". I added the `<h:inputHidden>`, to which I set the value with JS on click event and then I call the method of the bean. `<f:ajax event="click" listener="#{MeasureBean.foo()}" execute="editForm:checkpoint_id_to_rmeove" render="editForm:editor_line" />`   

Now it works like a charm